# Cube.js unable to join table from different dataSources

Tags: cube.js

In my cube.js server I have 2 tables from different data sources(both of them are postgres). I'm trying to create a join on these tables but get the following error

**Error: Joins across data sources aren't supported in community edition. Found data sources: dataSource_1, dataSource_2**

I have student_details cube and test_results cube (both cubes from different data source).

I'm trying to achieve a join on student id (test_results cube) and id (student_details cube ) but get the above error in bold.

Any help or work around for this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As error says this feature isn't part of open source Cube.js edition. As of now there's no way you can do it using open source Cube.js edition unless you implement it yourself.

Comment: Are there any plans to add this feature to the open source edition? I am also curious what are the reasons why this is not available. Thanks